# PageSpeed Caching Issue

Tags: nginx, caching, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Our web application developed in php(Yii Framework) uses Nginx server and PageSpeed for Caching purpose.Due to this caching sometimes some content and images are not loading.

There is a button given on the backend to clear Server Cache.So we have to manually clear the cache when some issues are raised.After clearing cache everything works fine.

Is there a way to automate Cache clearing?
Sometimes we do not get the updated data and after clearing the cache the data is visible. In this case, can i assume some db queries has been cached ?

What if i disable this pageSpeed cache ? Is it going to affect the performance of web app immensely ?

Really stuck into this.Please Help.

Here is the cache clearing code called when we clear cache by clicking the Cache clear button.

```
$output = shell_exec("touch /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush");
$a = shell_exec("echo $?");
```

Answer (score 0):

To run scheduled shell commands use [Linux`s crontab](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) command.

```
$ crontab -e
```

Than edit the file to run your commands like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2
```

Where:

1. Minute (0-59)
2. Hours (0-23)
3. Day (0-31)
4. Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5. Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])

`/path/to/command` – Script or command name to schedule

But this issue should not be resolved that way. Your problem is that you are not versioning your files correctly. PageSpeed module is not supposed to be flushed that way. You need to understand how caching mechanisms work and use Yii CLI to generate new path for your [assets](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets) as part of your deploy proccess

Comment: is pagespeed and yii assets are interlinked with each other.